# Copy and Paste to all empty cells below repeat at next non-empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

My data looks like this

```
ROW - Column A
1     England
2
3
4
5     Spain
6
7     Germany 
8
```

I need to start in A1 and paste into A2, A3, A4 - then realise that Spain is different to England and copy into A6 - then realise that Germany is different and copy that into A8. This is dummy data and the list is very long with lots of blank cells that need populating.

Comment: So you just want to fill down the blanks? A quick google on that gives me This: [excelcampus](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/fill-down-blank-cells/), and this: [trumpexcel](https://trumpexcel.com/fill-down-blank-cells-excel/). What did you try so far?

Comment: I can't add comment to your qustion but if you put a sample for your list (before and after ) to realise what's your problem

Comment: Is your data a part of a pivot table ?

Answer (score 0):

### Autofill Column

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFillColumn()
    
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty worksheet
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(sFirst)
    Dim fRow As Long: fRow = fCell.Row
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = lCell.Row
    If Not lRow > fRow Then Exit Sub ' last row not greater than first
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = lRow - fRow + 1
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = fCell.Resize(rCount)
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = crg.Value
    
    Dim OldValue As Variant
    Dim NewValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        NewValue = cData(r, 1)
        If IsEmpty(NewValue) Then
            cData(r, 1) = OldValue
        Else
            OldValue = NewValue
        End If
    Next r
    
    crg.Value = cData
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all entries in the column.
2. Goto Special, blanks.
3. Click inside the formula bar and type `=A1` (I believe your first entry is "A1").
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl+ENTER</kbd>.